# compactness and boundeness

Tags: general-topology

Use the open cover characterization of compactness to prove that if $f : [a,b] \to X$ is a continuous function and X is a metric space, the f is bounded.

Ok so I have a different approach. Does this work?

Proof: To show $f$ is bounded we must show that $f([a,b])$ is a bounded subset of $X$. So if $[a,b] \subseteq X$ then $[a,b]$ is compact if and only if $[a,b]$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence of elements of $[a,b]$. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem $\{x_n\}$ contains a convergent subsequence with limit $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $[a,b]$ is closed, $x \in [a,b]$. Thus, $[a,b]$ is compact. So $[a,b]= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: a_{i} \leq x_{i} \leq b_{i}$ for each $i=1,...,n\}$ is compact in $X^{n}$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Now we must show $f([a,b])$ is compact in $X$. Let $Y$ be a compact subset of $[a,b]$.

Suppose $f$ is continous and $X$ is a metric space. Let $\{U_{x}:x \in \mathscr{U} \}$ be an open cover of $f(Y)$ where $Y \in [a,b]$. For each point $y \in Y$, $f(y) \in f(Y)$ so $f(y) \in U_{x_{y}}$ for some $x_{y} \in \mathscr{U}$, that is $y \in f^{-1}(U_{x_{y}})$.

Thus, the collection $\{f^{-1}(U_{x}): x \in \mathscr{U}$ is a cover of $Y$. Since $f$ is continous each set $f^{-1}(U_{x})$ is open in $Y$, so $\{ f^{-1}(U_{x}):x \in \mathscr{U} \}$ is an open cover of $Y$.

Since $Y$ is compact, it has a finite subcover of 
$\{f^{-1}(U_{x_{}}),...f^{-1}(U_{x_{n}})\}$. Given $x \in f(Y)$, there exists $y\in Y$ such that $f(y)=x$, and $y \in f^{-1}(U_{x_{i}})$ for some $i$, so $x \in U_{x_{i}}$.

Thus, $\{U_{x},....,U_{x_{n}}\}$ is a finite subcover of $f(Y)$, so $f(Y)$ is compact. So by definition, since $f(Y)$ is compact then $f$ is bounded.

Is this right?

Comment: Hint: What is the meaning of $f$ is bounded?

Comment: It means that we have to show that f[a,b] is a bounded subset of X

Comment: Please look at my above changes and let me know what you think.